# How to combine elements in different lists

Tags: python

I am trying to use the below code to combine elements between two lists.

With the input of:

```
nested_array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I would like to have the output of:

```
[[1, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 7, 8, 9], ... [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

I try to use the below, but it doesn't seem to output in the format I want.

Can you please help?

```
def unique_combination(nested_array):
    try:
        for n1, array in enumerate(nested_array):
            for element in array:
                a = [element], list(nested_array[n1+1])
                print(a)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Also, instead of using print(), I tried to use the operation return.
But with the operation return, it is returning only one output.
Am I coding it correctly?

Comment: Return marks the point in which the function stores a value, to be used by the caller. It does not print anything.

Comment: Trying to use a code without understanding what it does will lead you to problems, try to come up with something on your own

Comment: Is `[4,1,2,3]` a valid output?

Comment: Hi @python_user_learn, Have you checked `itertools.combinations` for creating unique combinations from an `iterable`?. Please post some more details on what is to be achieved in this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the full desired output this looks like it gets you what you want. Note that This can be written in one line using list comprehension but it is a nasty one line.

```
nested_array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for list_index in range(len(nested_array) - 1):
    for marcher_index in range(list_index + 1, len(nested_array)):
        for ele in nested_array[list_index]:
            print([ele] + nested_array[marcher_index])
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 7, 8, 9]
[2, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 7, 8, 9]
[5, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
flatten_list = lambda ls: [item for sublist in ls for item in sublist]

nested_array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
unique_combination = [[i]+nested_array[j]  for j in range(1,len(nested_array)) 
                                           for i in flatten_list(nested_array[:j])]
print(unique_combination)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 5, 6],
 [1, 7, 8, 9],
 [2, 7, 8, 9],
 [3, 7, 8, 9],
 [4, 7, 8, 9],
 [5, 7, 8, 9],
 [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```